# Redux-form change field 2 value when field 1 changes

Tags: redux-form, react-select

What i need is a simple thing. If i choose country, it should set phone prefix field value.
I have redux-form with 2 Fields, where i pass react-select as component.

```
const BasicForm = props => {
const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, countries, phonePrefixes } = props;
return (
        <div className="form step1">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                    name="country"
                    className="form-control"
                    component={selectInput}
                    options={countries}
                    placeholder="Country"
                />
                <Field
                    name="phonePrefix"
                    className="form-control"
                    component={selectInput}
                    options={phonePrefixes}
                    placeholder="Prefix"
                />

                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>REGISTER
                    <i className="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
)};
```

Comment: http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/
Your form should get a `values` which you can use to set the value of your second field. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @atomman kinda misunderstood, what i need is the example, of how to use/rewrite onChange. Smth like this: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/152

But i still didnt figure out, how to do that properly.

Comment: @JevgeniKapparov have you ever found a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since redux-form 6.8
reduxForm() decorator supports  **onChange** handler with access to **values**, **props** and **dispatch** which gives you the ability to chain custom logic
See more: https://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/